# Two Visual Studio projects sharing the same code and Git

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am new to Git and need an advice.
I have 2 projects (client ans server parts), which share the same code (core components). And I cannot find the best way to put in VCS.

1. I cannot use a static library, because the common code has a lot of conditional statements for client/server.
2. If I use common linked folder, then I have to make commits in both projects manually. And there would be a mess in case of checkouts.
3. Git submodules sound like what I need, but as I understand, VS does not support submodules.
4. What I need is a "store only" project types in VS, which does not build anything, only store the source files. In this case I might include this project in both solutions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds more like a dependency issue than a VCS issue.

Comment: Use git submodules, VS 2017 Update 5 support it!